# How can I position text inside bubble chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js v3, I've made this bubble chart:

```
d3.json(JSON_URL, function(data) {

    data = JSON.parse(data)
    var nodes = pack.nodes(data);
    var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ","+ d.y + ")" ;});

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {return d.r; })
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {return d.children ? "#fff" : color(i)})
        .attr("opacity", 0.25)
        .attr("stroke-width", "2");


    node.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.name ;})
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "nodetext")
        .attr("data-classname", function(d) {return d.className;})
        .attr("style", function(d) {return "font-size:" + d.r/4;})
        .on("click", function(d) { window.open("https://twitter.com/hashtag/" + d.name.trim() + "\?src=hash"); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#2f4cff");
              d3.select(this).style("cursor", "pointer"); 

            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#000");
        });



    //problem here    
    node.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.value ;})
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "nodevalue")
        .attr("data-classname", function(d) {return d.className;})
        .attr("style", function(d) {return "font-size:" + d.r/4;});

}) ;
```

It's all well, expect the fact that the texts for `d.value` overlap the texts of `d.name`, while I want them to come under the `d.name`. The result should be something like this:

[image]

I tried to tweak the `nodevalue` class but it did not affect the positioning of texts.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `y` attribute to position vertically your text. Your code is a bit hard to test because we don't have access to your json, so blindly the code for the text part would be :

```
node.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.name ;})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("data-classname", function(d) {return d.className;})
    .attr("style", function(d) {return "font-size:" + d.r/4;})
    .on("click", function(d) { window.open("https://twitter.com/hashtag/" + d.name.trim() + "\?src=hash"); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#2f4cff");
          d3.select(this).style("cursor", "pointer"); 

        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#000");
    });

node.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.value ;})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "nodevalue")
    .attr("y", 15) // adding y attribute to offset vertically your text
    .attr("data-classname", function(d) {return d.className;})
    .attr("style", function(d) {return "font-size:" + d.r/4;});
```

Comment: Yes, that kinda works, but fixed value of `y` causes problem. When the bubble is small it's fine, but for large bubbles, it still overlaps with the line above. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yeah this is what I was afraid of, but couldn't really test it. What you can do is having an y attribute depending on the size of the bubble. Something like : `attr("y", d => d.r * 2 )`

Comment: This shouts the values out of bubbles.

Comment: I tried this one and works ok: `.attr("y", function(d) {return d.r/5 +15 ;})`